# Mongodb query to check whether a parameter is true and not null

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, dao, mongotemplate

I am using Spring Boot to create an application. I have created a class for a Data access object which will retrieve data from MongoDB.

Query: The objective of the query is to check whether the parameter(boolean variable - control) is **not null** and **true**

I have tried the following query:

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(
    Criteria.where({"control":{$ne:null}}),
Criteria.where("control").is(true)));
```

However, it is incorrect. What should we use for checking whether a variable is not null - $exists or $ne?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check null using if condition,

```
if(null != control) {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("status").is(control));
}
```

Sample **[`here`](https://github.com/jiajia919/socialshops-parent/blob/407167cb461ef4533a9eb7e5ad7d93ece347afd5/socialshops-crmorder-web-master/src/main/java/com/dhgate/socialshops/dao/impl/ShoppingCartDaoImpl.java#L142)**